# How to press an Element by Xpath

Tags: c#, android, selenium, xpath, appium

I would like to click an Element (in Appium, using Selenium) by following hierarchy:

```js
(1)LinerLayout --> android.widget.LinearLayout
   (0)RelativeLayout  --> android.widget.RelativeLayout
      (0)ImageView  -->  android.widget.ImageView
```

I have tried to use the following Xpath but without any success.

```js
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using  = "//'android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]/android.widget.ImageView[0]'")]
 public IList<IWebElement> SearchStreetButton { get; set; }
```

Comment: try  removing the single inverted commas as -`"//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]/android.widget.ImageView[0]"`

Comment: perfect. 
unfortunately, I Can't mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the ***comments*** as well to resolve such a problem, the `X-Path` shall not include the single inverted commas unless used with `contains` or any other string operation -

Changing the x-path as follows shall work -

```
"//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]/android.wid‌​get.ImageView[0]"
```